# max value 50% of other values

Tags: javascript, validation, input, max

I'm very new to javascript, I'm trying to input a maximum value of 50% of the selling price, please advise

I have two fields "sale_price" and "discount"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ebHe.jpg)

How does JavaScript limit and change the discount nominal input so that it does not exceed 50% of the selling price

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `"How does JavaScript limit and change the discount nominal input so that it does not exceed 50% of the selling price?"` Well, however you program it to do so.

Comment: I asked the same thing sir, can JavaScript solve that problem, here I have a selling_price value, can I change the discount input?

Comment: Are you asking if you can input a value in a text field? Because the answer to that is "yes, and you don't need Javascript to do that, you just need to be able to type into the field". You're going to have to be much more specific about what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and how it's working or not working.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that when inputting there was validation that didn't allow the nominal value to be no more than the selling price, sir, sorry I was wrong

Comment: Again, is this a program you're writing or one for which you have access to the source code? If so, presumably you can show us the code that does this validation. If you're just trying to pay less for something, I'm afraid we can't help with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an if / else statement here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Basically say

```
if(sale_price < (normal_price * 0.5)) {
   var something = (normal_price * 0.5)
  } else {var something = sale_price}
```

Or the better route which I prefer ternary linked below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator

```
sale_price < (normal_price * 0.5)?
sale_price = (normal_price * 0.5):
sale_price
```

You'd want to chose the approach based on the type of variable that the sale_price is. If it's a const you'll need to create a different variable and I'd use an if / else statement. If it's changeable you'd do better to use an ternary.

Hope this helps!